# Find lost rows after a pyspark DataFrame join

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Given 2 spark DataFrames, `csv_df` and `other_df`, I need to join them and then figure out which rows from `csv_df` were lost in the join.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    csv_df = self.sqlContext.read.load('csv_table.parquet')
    csv_df = csv_df.withColumn(
        "mid", monotonically_increasing_id()
    )
    other_df = self.sqlContext.read.load('other_table.parquet')
    joined = csv_df.join(other_df, ['col1', 'col2'])
    found_rows = joined.select('mid').distinct()
    not_found_ids = csv_df.where(~csv_df.mid.isin(found_rows))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix my code to get the non-joined rows?

Answer (score 0):

Although I would still like to know why my above-posted code doesn't work, I've realized that I can just do another join to answer my question:

```
csv_df = self.sqlContext.read.load('csv_table.parquet')
csv_df = csv_df.withColumn(
    "mid", monotonically_increasing_id()
)
other_df = self.sqlContext.read.load('other_table.parquet')
joined = csv_df.join(other_df, ['col1', 'col2'])
found_rows = joined.select('mid').distinct()
not_found_rows = csv_df.selectExpr('mid').subtract(found_rows)
not_found_ids = csv_df.join(not_found_rows, 'mid')
```